# passing an array element in yii google chart it , it passes null value intead of its values

Tags: javascript, php, yii, google-visualization

View:

```
<?php
    $nodes = $gw->searchNodes();
    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        $user= $node->getpdsout();
        foreach($user as $key=>$val){
            $ls = $val['elapsed'];
            var_dump($ls);//
        }
    }
?>
```

I got:

```
output :- NULL
string(16) "16.3080555555556"
NULL
NULL
```

I thought it passes only the first `NULL` , it is not able to pass other values ,even if I try with php filter , but it doesn't work , someone has suggested me to use `$ls = (float) val['ealsped']` , then on that it shows

```
float(0)
float(16.308055555556)
float(0)
float(0)
```

Java script file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6" >  
        <?php
        //very useful google chart
            $this->widget('ext.Hzl.google.HzlVisualizationChart', array('visualization' => 'PieChart',
                'data' => array(
                            array('Occupied ', 'Hours per Day'),
                            array('Occupied',$ls),// here got ["Occupied",null],instead of ["Occupied", 16.3080555555556]
                            array('Not Occupied', 16.3080555555556),
                            array('Occupied', 5.45388888888889),                       
                          ),
                'options' => array('title' => 'Occupancy Sensor')));
         ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

output log using fire bug:

```
- google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["Occupied ","Hours per Day"],["Occupied",null],["Not Occupied",16.308055555556],["Occupied",5.4538888888889]]);
```